# unable to send a notification to myself

Tags: android, apigee

After I followed all the steps for the `push notification sample app`. I wasn't able to send a notifaction to myself. I could send a pushmessage from my PC to my phone, but when I use the button `Send myself a Notification` nothing happens.

I am using Android sdk

After starting the app I do see that my Device is Registerd

Here is my settings.java

```
package com.ganyo.pushtest;

/** Change these values to match your setup! */
public class Settings {

    static final String UNASSIGNED_ORG_VALUE = "";

  // Google Client Id from Google API Console
  static final String GCM_SENDER_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";

  // Notifier Name in App Services
  static final String NOTIFIER = "androidDev";

  static final String API_URL = "https://api.usergrid.com";

  static final String ORG = "xxxxxxx";
  static final String APP = "sandbox";

  // set these if you want to use a user login
  static final String USER = null;
  static final String PASSWORD = null;
}
```

I'm not sure what the UNASSIGNED_ORG_VALUE should be.

Thx in advance.

Comment: why you want to send yourself a push notification? why dont just use local ones?

Comment: try naming your notifier just "android"

Answer (score 0):

No need to assign any value to UNASSIGNED_ORG_VALUE. It's only used to check that you've entered the other values.

Please check your Android logs as well as the Apigee Console to see what error messages might have been generated during your push attempt. This will help you debug the issue.

Finally, you could try providing your notifier name here in all lowercase. (Note: This shouldn't generally be necessary, but I've heard there may be a issue that affects notifier name resolution.)